# Search and filter page using code igniter

Tags: search, filter, codeigniter-2

Started using code igniter recently and been trying to make a page that filters events by certain parameters .I have the view page that contains an input type search (searches keywords in database)and a drop down filter list that filters by name of event,location and pricing.however I need help in querying the search results from database and displaying it on my view page .Anyone with an idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

when you are submitting a form submit it to the controller method and get the post value in controller method

```
function search()
{

    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->load->model('mymodel');
    $result = $this->mymodel->getSearchResults($keyword);
    $data['results'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('search_results',$data);
}
```

And in your model

```
function getSearchResults($keyword){
    $this->db->like('column_name',$keyword,'after');
    return $this->db->get('tablename')->result();
    // or you can write query simple way instead of Active Record
    // $query = "SELECT BLah blah FROM mytable WHERE column_name like '$keyword%'";
    // return $this->db->query($query)->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much,appreciate it

Comment: if you think answer is useful you can accept it so other people dont answer it or it will still drag peoples attraction